# degit running error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '~/.degit'

Tags: node.js, npm, degit

I'm using Deepin v20.8, a Debian-based distribution. I try to install `degit` an npm package.

1. I first install `node.js`. It is in `/usr/bin/node` and `npm` is in `/usr/bin/npm`
2. I then run `sudo npm install -g degit`, it is installed in `/usr/bin/degit`
3. Then I run `degit`, it raises the following error:

```
node:fs:1452
  handleErrorFromBinding(ctx);
  ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '~/.degit'
    at Object.readdirSync (node:fs:1452:3)
    at walk (/usr/lib/node_modules/degit/dist/bin.js:525:40)
    at sync (/usr/lib/node_modules/degit/dist/bin.js:591:3)
    at main (/usr/lib/node_modules/degit/dist/bin.js:5607:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/degit/dist/bin.js:5712:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'scandir',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '~/.degit'
}

Node.js v18.16.0
```

(I alias my user directory by `~`)

It seems I've followed every instructions in the doc, I just don't understand the problem. Do I use the wrong user account to install it? I don't know which step cause the problem, the way I install `npm` or `degit`? How can I fix the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems funny, the way I solve it is to create a directory `~/.degit`. I have no idea why this won't be automatically done by the installation.

Comment: Per the issues, [your fix is the right workaround](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/degit/issues/345). This would only take a few lines of code to fix in `degit` itself, but the project seems to be abandoned.

Comment: As @ZacAnger indicated, `degit` is currently abandoned, for information [here](https://github.com/tiged/tiged) is a community-maintained fork